# How can I center a set of equations and make a line under one of them?

Tags: equations, rules

[image: Set of equations]

This is something I need to achieve, I have a problem with the last equation. How can I underline this the same way as above? I've tried writing it as one fraction, but the other fraction in numerator gets smaller and the equal sign isn't in line with other signs. Could you please advise?

```
begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{2}{3}=0,66666\ 66667\ (-) \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 3 \cdot 9}=0,02469\ 13580\ (+) \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 5 \cdot 9^{2}}=0,00164\ 60905\ (+) \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 7 \cdot 9^{3}}=0,00013\ 06421\ (+) \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 9 \cdot 9^{4}}=0,00001\ 12901\ (-) \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 11 \cdot 9^{5}}=0,00000\ 10264\ (-) \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 13 \cdot 9^{6}}=0,00000\ 00965\ (-) \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 15 \cdot 9^{7}}=0,00000\ 00093\ (-) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
```

This is the code, but don't know what about last part...

Comment: please provide what you do so far. Retyping equations from your image is not really fun for us ...

Comment: You could just draw a horizontal line using \rule or \hline (if in a tabular),

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 3):

I would construct this in a regular `array`, provided that there is no requirement for the construction to break across the page boundary. Here is such an implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.1}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764
  \begin{array}{ >{\displaystyle}r @{} >{{}}l c}
                       \frac{2}{3} &= 0.66666\,66667 & (-) \\
       \frac{2}{3 \cdot 3 \cdot 9} &= 0.02469\,13580 & (+) \\
     \frac{2}{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 9^2} &= 0.00164\,60905 & (+) \\
     \frac{2}{3 \cdot 7 \cdot 9^3} &= 0.00013\,06421 & (+) \\
     \frac{2}{3 \cdot 9 \cdot 9^4} &= 0.00001\,12901 & (-) \\
    \frac{2}{3 \cdot 11 \cdot 9^5} &= 0.00000\,10264 & (-) \\
    \frac{2}{3 \cdot 13 \cdot 9^6} &= 0.00000\,00965 & (-) \\
    \frac{2}{3 \cdot 15 \cdot 9^7} &= 0.00000\,00093 & (-) \\[0.7\normalbaselineskip]
    \hline
                                   &= 0.69314\,71805
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

use the `align*` environment from amsmath and a simple `\cline` just like in a tabular

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
    \frac{2}{3}                    &= 0.66666\,66667  ~(-) \\
    \frac{2}{3 \cdot 3 \cdot 9}    &= 0.02469\,13580  ~(+) \\
    \frac{2}{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 9^2}  &= 0.00164\,60905  ~(+) \\
    \frac{2}{3 \cdot 7 \cdot 9^3}  &= 0.00013\,06421  ~(+) \\
    \frac{2}{3 \cdot 9 \cdot 9^4}  &= 0.00001\,12901  ~(-) \\
    \frac{2}{3 \cdot 11 \cdot 9^5} &= 0.00000\,10264  ~(-)\\
    \frac{2}{3 \cdot 13 \cdot 9^6} &= 0.00000\,00965  ~(-)\\
    \frac{2}{3 \cdot 15 \cdot 9^7} &= 0.00000\,00093  ~(-)\\\cline{1-2}
                                   &= 0.69314\,71805
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As possible starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array,siunitx}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$}}
    \begin{aligned}
\frac{2}{3}                 & = \num{0,6666666667}\ (-)   \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 3\cdot 9}   & = \num{0,0246913580}\ (+)   \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 3\cdot 9^2} & = \num{0,0016460905}\ (+)   \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 3\cdot 9^3} & = \num{0,0001306421}\ (+)   \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 3\cdot 9^4} & = \num{0,0000112901}\ (-)   \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 3\cdot 9^5} & = \num{0,0000010264}\ (-)   \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 3\cdot 9^6} & = \num{0,0000000965}\ (-)   \\
\frac{2}{3\cdot 3\cdot 9^7} & = \num{0,0000000093}\ (-)   \\[1ex]
    \hline
                            & = \num{0,6931471805}
    \end{aligned}
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

The package `array` serves to determine `>{$}c<{$}`, `siunitx` for macro `\num{...}` which enable to grouping numbers in 3. For line is used standard `\hline` from `tabular` environment.

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of `tabular`?

Comment: @eqgreg, only for draw line. As I see from your answer, this can be achieved without tabular environment with use of `cline`.

Comment: I was mainly objecting to `tabular` instead of `array`. However, if you're using `array`, you can avoid the inner `align`, can't you?